# Sequelize sort query by number

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

Hey stack overflow I have a query that I am making to my mysql database. I would like to order it by number. Here is what I currently have

```
 const frequencies = await DeliveryFrequency.findAndCountAll({
      offset,
      limit,
      order: [['code', 'ASC']],
      where: {
        tenantId: filters.tenantId,
        ...(filters.frequencyCodes?.length > 0 ? { code: { [Op.in]: filters.frequencyCodes } } : {}),
      },
    });
```

My data set looks like

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "d8fb16b5-3b49-415b-8036-43d15a2505d3",
  
            "code": "1",
            "translations": {
                "en": {
                    "displayText": "1 month"
                }
            },
            "displayText": "1 month",
            "language": "en"
        },
        {
            "id": "bfac3cd9-95dd-4919-98ac-c9f3d6e0874d",
         
            "code": "10",
            "translations": {
                "en": {
                    "displayText": "10 days"
                }
            },
            "displayText": "10 days",
            "language": "en"
        },
        {
            "id": "2548e225-53bf-417c-8f0e-9fc7df21061b",
            "code": "45",
            "translations": {
                "en": {
                    "displayText": "45 days"
                }
            },
            "displayText": "45 days",
            "language": "en"
        },
        {
            "id": "89a49423-779c-4a56-9b7e-28fafce0202a",
            "code": "5",
            "translations": {
                "en": {
                    "displayText": "5 days"
                }
            },
            "displayText": "5 days",
            "language": "en"
        }
    ],
    "offset": 0,
    "limit": 20,
    "totalCount": 4
}
```

I want to numerically sort the 'code' property as 1, 5, 10, 45. However when I do order: [['code', 'ASC']] it doesnt order them properly. Its ordered in my code example shown above. Any ideas or approach on how I can sort numerically?

Comment: I think you just need to put an ORDER BY in there after the where, and have it order by code.  Citation -
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-order-by/

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that `code` always stores integer numbers as strings you can use `Sequelize.cast` like this:

```js
order: [[Sequelize.cast('code', 'integer'), 'ASC']]
```

Comment: Sometimes my dataset is not going to be an integer but a string. How would I order strings as well?

Comment: Then you need to indicate in the post the desired result in case when you have mixed codes

Comment: Well it's really always going to be strings. I would like to sort those strings as appropriately as possible.

Comment: Nevertheless you need to indicate what you underdstand by `appropriately`. SHow a couple of examples